# Grid : force cell width of second row independant

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have this code that displays a row with multiple columns.
When the width of the screen goes below a limit (with media-queries) I would like certain cells to pass into a second line but with widths independent of the first line.

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
    <div class="c1">1</div>
    <div class="c2">2</div>
    <div class="c3">3</div>
    <div class="c4">4</div>
    <div class="c5">5</div>
    <div class="c6">6</div>
    <div class="c7">7</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid {display: grid; width: 100%; grid-template-columns: 50px auto 70px 250px 60px 60px 60px;}
@media screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
.grid {grid-template-columns: 50px auto 70px 250px;}
.grid .c5 {grid-column-start: 1;}
}
```

Result large screen :

```
+-----------------------------------+
| 1 |   2   | 3 |   4   | 5 | 6 | 7 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Result screen < 1070px (not what I want) :
I have a line break in cells 5,6 and 7 but their width depends on the width of the column above the first line.

```
+-----------------------------------+
| 1 |       2      | 3 |      4     |
+-----------------------------------+
| 5 |       6      | 7 |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Is it possible to have this result with for example a width of 33% for the columns of the second row like this from this HTML code?

```
+-----------------------------------+
| 1 |       2      | 3 |      4     |
+-----------------------------------+
|      5    |      6     |    7     |
+-----------------------------------+
```

Comment: Just have more columns, and have the cells span multiple columns. On the first row they might span two or three columns each, on the second row they might span five or six columns each.

Comment: The required result not a grid and so CSS-Grid is not appropriate here. I suspect flexbox will get you closest but even that cannot detect when a line breaks or overflow occurs. Targeting a specific row in flexbox or CSS-Grid for that matter is not possible as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the required elements in a separate div which, at larger sizes is opened up with `display: contents`.

At the lower width, we move the wrapper to the second row, make it full width and then apply flexbox and make the contents equal width.

```css
.wrap {
  display: contents;
}

[class^="c"] {
  border: 1px solid green;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px auto 70px 250px repeat(3, 60px);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1070px) {
  .grid {
    grid-template-columns: 50px auto 70px 250px;
  }
  .grid .wrap {
    grid-column: 1 / -1;
    display: flex;
  }
  .wrap div {
    flex: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="c1">1</div>
  <div class="c2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
  <div class="c3">3</div>
  <div class="c4">4</div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="c5">5</div>
    <div class="c6">6</div>
    <div class="c7">7</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what it seemed to me, it's not possible with this HTML code. So I'm going to put a sub-container.